# The best way to delete printed results from the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, post, get

I have a question about safely deleting row in database.
For example I have an array of rows and I print it. It looks like this.

```
text 1 - delete
text 2 - delete
text 3 - delete
...
text n - delete
```

Behind the text information there is a delete link. And my question is what is the best way when user click on delete to delete this record. I heard about to set the links href on actual id of the text information like that:

```
<a href=?toDelete=1>delete</a>
```

And when user click on link I can get it by _GET, then I can delete the row by ID. I don't think this is the best practice at all, if is, then tell me. By the way I use a Laravel framework so are there any options to use some built-in function? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a button or a link inside form:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('texts.destroy', $id) }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button>Delete text</button>
</form>
```

Or, if you use Laravel Collection forms:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'Delete', 'route' => array('texts.destroy', $id))) !!}
    <button class="btn-xs btn-danger">Delete text</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Or with Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/texts/1',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so if I get for example 50 query results, I need a 50 forms for each link?

Comment: Why not? It will not affect on website perfomance much. Also, you can use Ajax if you want to speed it up.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: I've updated my post with Ajax code. Just use variable instead of hardcoded `1` text id, if you'll choose ajax way of course.

Comment: I don't know how to execute a sql delete query from ajax. I think that it is not possible, but I can pass it to the php code, but how? Can you show me example of usage.

Comment: Ajax code will just call same `destroy()` method of you RESTful controller. So, just create and test a `destroy()` action and it should work with posted Ajax code (as well as with forms).